How to implement transaction per graphql request
I am trying to setup an Apollo GraphQL server with a Postgresql backend accessed through Prisma.
I want a '1 client request' - '1 db transaction', even if the GraphQL request contains a sequence of e.g. mutations.
My feeling is that the combination of an Apollo GraphQL context and Prisma interactive transactions should make this possible, but I wonder if anyone knows of a simple example that implements this (I am getting lost in the options and types and ...), or if a better solution is available to achieve the 1 req/1 txn approach that also interests me to learn
Any pointers or tips welcomed
Tx a lot!
Peter

I managed to work around it by using the Apollo graphql function wrapped in a Prisma interactive transaction and invoke that from an express handler.
app.post('/gql2', async (req, res) => {
    const { query, variables } = req.body;
    try {
        const result = await prismaClient.$transaction(async (tx) => {
            return await graphql({
                schema,
                source: query,
                variableValues: variables,
                contextValue: tx,
            });
        });
        res.json(result);
    } catch (error:any) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
});

In the resolver,it's easy to pick up the Prisma tx and use that for all database access
Not sure I can do without the node express detour but like it's now it seems to be ok
Peter
